# How can I disable multithreading in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I have a SQL Server 2017 Standard edition database that uses multiple threads on the commands.

For example, I run simple select and database open more threads. This is undesirable because I have purchased a license for a limited number of users and if the some command takes longer occurs blocking access to data. How can I disable it?

Thanks for answer

```
DECLARE @loginname NCHAR(128)
DECLARE @spid SMALLINT
DECLARE @EventType NCHAR(30)
DECLARE @Parameters SMALLINT
DECLARE @EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT 
    loginame, nt_domain, nt_username, hostname, login_time, program_name,
    CASE 
       WHEN dbid = 0 THEN N'' 
       ELSE DB_NAME(dbid)
    END,
    spid, open_tran, net_library, cpu, physical_io,
    memusage, blocked, status, last_batch, cmd, context_info 
FROM 
    master.dbo.sysprocesses  
WHERE 
    net_library <> N'' 
    AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher' 
    AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Alert Engine' 
    AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Job invocation engine'

DECLARE c1 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT loginame, spid 
    FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses  
    WHERE net_library <> N'' 
      AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher' 
      AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Alert Engine' 
      AND program_name <> N'SQLAgent - Job invocation engine'

OPEN c1

WHILE 1 = 1 
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @loginname, @spid

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
       BREAK

    DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@spid)
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

For example output with 7threads with same select command:

```
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 405 |  0 | 4 | 0 | runnable  | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 218 | 77 | 0 | 0 | suspended | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 265 | 93 | 0 | 0 | suspended | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 219 | 30 | 0 | 0 | suspended | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 219 | 65 | 0 | 0 | suspended | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 141 | 39 | 0 | 0 | runnable  | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 203 | 75 | 0 | 0 | suspended | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
| WS2012 | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.217 | Helios Orange - HeliosMain 2.0.2018.0600 HEIQ0100-22970|2 | Helios001 | 62 | 0 | TCP/IP |    | 125 | 20 | 0 | 0 | runnable  | 2018-07-28 19:47:17.207 | SELECT |
```

Comment: You might also consider switching to a free DB server Like Postgres or MariaDB  (MySQL). Then you can have all the treads and RAM you want for free. If you're only using MSSQL Standard with 16GB, there isn't much of a reason to pay for it., since you're not getting any of the high-end features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable query parallelism with:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show',1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism',1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

That said, the solution for blocking problems is not turning off parallelism. The cure for that is query and index tuning along with an appropriate isolation level and/or turning on the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option.